# How does KMS (Windows Server 2008 R2) differentiate clients?

Tags: image, licensing, kms

I have recently installed a KMS Server in our domain and deployed 75 new Windows 7 machines using an image I made using Acronis True Image. There are 2 variations of this image rolled out currently.
When I go to activate the machines it returns that the KMS count is not sufficient.
On the server with a `slmgr /dlv` it shows:

```
Key Management Service is enabled on this machine.
Current count: 2
Listening on Port: 1688
DNS publishing enabled
KMS Priority: Normal

KMS cumulative requests received from clients: 366
Failed requests received: 2
Requests with License status unlicensed: 0
Requests with License status licensed: 0
Requests with License status Initial Grace period: 1
Requests with License statusLicense expired or hardware out of tolerance: 0
Requests with License status Non genuine grace period: 0
Requests with License status Notification: 363
```

Is it to do with the fact that I've used the same image for all the PC's? If so how do I get round this. Would changing the SID help?

OK knowing I've been thick whats the best way to rectify the situation. Can I sysprep the machines to OOBE on each individual machine? Or would NewSID work?

Comment: Why the buggery did you use TrueImage and not say, WDS to get clean installs, then GPOs to install software?

Comment: This may help: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897418  (Though I haven't used it since NT4.0, so it may not)

Comment: Though, now that I read a bit more, I'm leaning towards the 'not': http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/11/03/3291024.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, lets jsut say ignoring documentation is never wise, and you did so. Your images should be sysprepped and thus geneate unique identities. as they obvfiously are not - you are in trouble.

Comment: OK knowing I've been thick whats the best way to rectify the situation. Can I sysprep the machines to OOBE on each individual machine? Or would NewSSID work?

Comment: NewSID may destroy a Vista or Win7 machine. MS has removed it from their website and pointed to an article on why it's was a bad idea from the get-go. Use `sysprep`.

Comment: @chris S - Use Sysprep oobe?

Comment: @Joe Taylor, yep, SysPrep, OOBE, not Generalized, Reboot or Shutdown (doesn't matter much, though reboot would likely get things done quicker).

Comment: Installed WDS and took the time to learn to do it the proper way. Its a much better way that the method I'd originally used.

Answer (score 2):

The CMID of the workstation needs to be unique. As TomTom pointed out, sysprep is the way to go and is a requirement regardless of your imaging process, otherwise the operating system is unsupported by Microsoft. Sysprep does way more than just change your sid or cmid.

Scott McArthur who is a Senior Support Escalation Engineer at Microsoft wrote a blog that goes in to detail about this exact issue here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2009/10/16/kms-host-client-count-not-increasing-due-to-duplicate-cmid-s.aspx